# Why does the USPTO require that you sign a provisional patent application with an 'S-signature' when this signature can easily be forged?

Tags: provisional-application

When signing the provisional patent application form it must be signed with a so called s-signature. Such a signature consists of nothing more then your first, middle and last name encompassed by two `/` symbols. Such a signature is not unique and can easily be forged. [Here are some examples of valid s-signature formats](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/sigexamples_alt_text.pdf).

Why does the USPTO want the applicant to include such a signature when it seemingly adds no value at all?

Comment: This link looks relevant. https://www.adobe.com/sign/esignature-resources/s-signature.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing, but don't know for sure, that the USPTO is assuming the potential for forgery is acceptable. Many people do not have access to printers and scanners. The use of the forward slashes communicates that the person filling out the form is indicating the typed name is an intentional representation of a signature. [This link](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/uspto_signatures_june2020.pdf) discusses the digital signature policy.